# Using an if statement on a php function

Tags: php, function, object, if-statement

Im trying to make a function that tests whether a triangle has equal sides and then print the answer but my function doesnt work. Any ideas ?

```
 public function typeOfTriangle()
 {

    if ($this->lengthSideOne == $this->lengthSideTwo == $this->lengthBase)
    {echo 'the triangle is equal'}
 );
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't string together `==` operations. You need to use `AND` (aka `&&`).

Like this:

```
public function typeOfTriangle()
{
    if ( $this->lengthSideOne == $this->lengthSideTwo && $this->lengthSideTwo == $this->lengthBase ) {
        echo 'the triangle is equal';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function typeOfTriangle()
 {

```
if ($this->lengthSideOne == $this->lengthSideTwo && $this->lengthSideOne == $this->lengthBase)
{echo 'the triangle is equal';}
```

);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public function typeOfTriangle()
 {

    if ($this->lengthSideOne == $this->lengthSideTwo && $this->lengthSideTwo == $this->lengthBase)
    {echo 'the triangle is equal'}
 );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is your parenthetical notation.

```
public function typeOfTriangle() {
 if($this->lengthSideOne == $this->lengthSideTwo && $this->lengthSideTwo == $this->lengthBase) {
     echo 'the triangle is equal';
  }
}
```

if your using brances the syntax is:

```
if( ...condition... ) {
   ...do stuff...
}
```

brace-less conditionals work like this

```
if(...condition...)
   ...do stuff...
```

more info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 0):

```
public function typeOfTriangle()
 {

    if ( $this->lengthSideOne == $this->lengthSideTwo == $this->lengthBase )
    { echo 'the triangle is equal'; }
    // remove this );
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass the variable to the function.

When you call it do this. (each number is a side)

```
typeOfTriangle(2,2,4)
```

Then change the start of your function to retrieve this data and assign it to $this like below.

```
    public function typeOfTriangle($side1, $side2, $side3)
 {

    if ($side1 == $side2 && $side2 == $side3) //this check side 1,2,3 are equal with 2 statements. 
    {echo 'the triangle is equal';}
 }
```

Comment: i didn't down vote, but i can say your getting them because you dont' always "need to" pass params to a function. i see the word public in the function declaration, that means this is probably part of a larger class where $this->sideX is being set. in that context you dont need to pass variables to the function to use them.

Comment: I also wasn't the one to down vote, but as well what xero said your original answer still included the incorrect if statement (which I see you have changed now) and you have a syntax error with ');'